# To What Should I Change the Targeted Processor Architecture of my Project?

Tags: windows, uwp, visual-studio-2019, cpu-architecture, configurationmanager

I have created a .NET Core Winforms app (using C#) that I want to submit to the Windows app Store. Following what it says [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net), I added a Windows Application Packaging Project to my solution:

[image]

I tried creating the Package, but it failed with this err msg:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the
> project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the
> reference
> "C:\Users\bclay\source\repos\F4F_Core\F4F_Core\bin\x86\Release\netcoreapp3.1\win-x86\F4F_Core.dll",
> "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider
> changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through
> the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
> between your project and references, or take a dependency on
> references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
> processor architecture of your project.   WapProjTemplate1    C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 2124

So it says to "consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through the Configuration Manager"

This is what Configuration Manager shows:

[image]

It allows me to add a New or Edit the existing:

[image]

...but I don't know what I should try to add or change here.

The parts of the WapProjTemplate1.wapproj file that may be relevant are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt; '15.0'">
    <VisualStudioVersion>15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x86">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x86</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x86">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x86</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|ARM64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|ARM64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>ARM64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|AnyCPU">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|AnyCPU">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WapProjPath Condition="'$(WapProjPath)'==''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\DesktopBridge\</WapProjPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WapProjPath)\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>235c6e85-cf17-455c-93b8-efdd1826a90e</ProjectGuid>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.18362.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.14393.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
. . .
    <HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>0</HoursBetweenUpdateChecks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x86'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|ARM'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|ARM'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|ARM64'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|ARM64'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
  </PropertyGroup>
. . .
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\F4F_Core\F4F_Core.csproj">
      <SkipGetTargetFrameworkProperties>True</SkipGetTargetFrameworkProperties>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(WapProjPath)\Microsoft.DesktopBridge.targets" />
</Project>
```

I did not change any default settings in these (processor architecture) values. What do I need to change to get the package to successfully create?

Selecting Project > Properties for the main project shows this:

[image]

Selecting Project Properties for the Windows Application Packaging Project shows this:

[image]

So as you can see, the Configuration and Platform are considered "N/A" and are thus non-editable.

### UPDATE

While in the "Create App Packages" process, I retained the default "Neutral / Release (Any CPU)" selection as shown here:

[image]

### UPDATE 2

This answer [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/461f4b46-f928-40da-8e49-7fd0f4754fd4/uwpmismatch-between-processor-architecture?forum=wpdevelop] on a Microsoft forum indicates that "Any" should not be selected, but rather "x86"

But when I change the main project's target from Any to x86, it doesn't change the value above:

[image]

To be clear, the "Platform" dropdown above only has one item in it: "Active (Any CPU)"

### UPDATE 3

In accord with NicoZhu's request that I "send feedback with Visual Studio for this issue," I opened the project and was immediately greeted by this:

[image]

### UPDATE 4

So I noticed there were some notifications in Visual Studio. One said that in order to develop UWP apps, I had to turn on Developer Mode. So I did that...

[image]

After that was turned on, I got:

[image]

Ater VS restarted, I tried again to Create App Package, but got this:

[image]

...but I don't know what the errors in the app manifest are, so can't fix them without that knowledge.

Is the err msg referring to the values in Package.appxmanifest?

### UPDATE 5

The various properties for the solution as a whole and for its two projects follows.

The solution:

[image]

The Winforms .NET Core app's properties:

[image]

The Windows Application Packaging Project's properties:

[image]

### UPDATE 6

The updated answer below *did* create the packages, but when I then tried to run the Windows Packaging App, I got an err re: mismatched processor architectures in the two projects. Please see my follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64864614/what-must-i-do-to-fix-the-mismatch-between-processor-architecture-of-my-projec).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the testing with blank project, I could reproduce this issue, and we suggest you send feedback with Visual Studio for this issue. And currently we have a workaround that edit the Winform **platform target** as **x86** (not Platform dropdown), publish application package template as x86 release package.

**Update**

**Right click winform project-> Properties-> build- >Platform.**

[image]

**Right the package template project -> Publish -> Create app packages-> Sideloading-> Skip package signing**

Only check x86 Architecture.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, NicoZhu; can you provide some step-by-step instructions for how to "edit the Winform platform target as x86 (not Platform dropdown), publish application package template as x86 release package"?

Comment: Your update did create the packages, but when I then tried to run the Windows Packaging App, I get an err re: mismatched processor architectures in the two projects. Please see my followup question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64864614/what-must-i-do-to-fix-the-mismatch-between-processor-architecture-of-my-projec