# What must I do to fix the "mismatch between processor architecture" of my projects?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2019, cpu-architecture, configurationmanager

I have built a Winforms .NET Core app that I want to submit to the Windows Store.

In line with that goal, I was able to create an app package from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64810192/to-what-should-i-change-the-targeted-processor-architecture-of-my-project/).

Now I want to get my app onto the App Store. Following the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-debug), it tells me that if I "created the package by using Visual Studio" I should, "Set the packaging project as the startup project, and then press F5 to start your app."

So I did that, but got this err msg:

> Error MSB3270 There was a mismatch between the processor architecture
> of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of
> the reference
> "C:\Users\bclay\source\repos\F4F_Core\F4F_Core\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\F4F_Core.dll",
> "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider
> changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through
> the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
> between your project and references, or take a dependency on
> references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
> processor architecture of your project.   WapProjTemplate1    C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 2123

[image]

As I followed the specific instructions at the previously mentioned answer (the "Update" part of that answer), I don't know now what I should change, or how, exactly, to do so.

Following the answer given to the previous question, here are the options I selected for the Winforms app:

[image]

...and for the Windows Packing app:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have not specificed the solution platforms to X86, please edit it to x86 before press F5.

[image]